# heroku python manage py syncdb not working

Tags: ruby, django, heroku

I have gone through the heroku, tutorial as mentioned in the dev center. 
The app shows and works fine. 
When I try heroku logs i get the logs as seen here:

```
2012-11-20T12:40:13+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-11-20T12:40:13+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb`
2012-11-20T12:40:13+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-20T12:40:43+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2012-11-20T12:40:44+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 128
2012-11-20T12:40:44+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-11-20T13:28:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb` by emailaddress@gmail.com
2012-11-20T13:28:04+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-20T13:28:04+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-11-20T13:28:04+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb`
2012-11-20T13:28:34+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2012-11-20T13:28:35+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 128
2012-11-20T13:28:35+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
```

which means that is working, however when i try:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

it does not run, and the stacktrace is here:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
/Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:103: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.1
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    Backtrace:   /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `initialize'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `open'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `block in start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:125:in `rendezvous_session'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:112:in `run_attached'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
                 /Users/myusername/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku run python manage.py syncdb
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.33.1 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

What is possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and managed to find a solution. I would start by checking the heroku logs with the command:

`heroku logs`

That should provide more insight. A common problem for syncdb not working is that you have not updated your requirements.txt

To do so pipe pip freeze into requirements.txt

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This may not be the exact problem you were having, but heroku logs should be a good start.